# Go goroutine test failing Expected number of calls

Tags: go, testify

I'm new to Go here. I am trying to test the function call inside my Go routine but it fails with the error message

> Expected number of calls (8) does not match the actual number of calls
> (0).

My test code goes like:

```
package executor

import (
    "testing"
  "sync"
    "github.com/stretchr/testify/mock"
)

type MockExecutor struct {
    mock.Mock
  wg sync.WaitGroup
}

func (m *MockExecutor) Execute() {
  defer m.wg.Done()
}

func TestScheduleWorksAsExpected(t *testing.T) {

    scheduler := GetScheduler()
    executor := &MockExecutor{}
    scheduler.AddExecutor(executor)

    // Mock exptectations
    executor.On("Execute").Return()
    

    // Function Call
  executor.wg.Add(8)
    scheduler.Schedule(2, 1, 4)
  executor.wg.Wait()

  executor.AssertNumberOfCalls(t, "Execute", 8)

}
```

and my application code is:

```
package executor

import (
    "sync"
    "time"
)

type Scheduler interface {
    Schedule(repeatRuns uint16, coolDown uint8, parallelRuns uint64)
    AddExecutor(executor Executor)
}

type RepeatScheduler struct {
    executor  Executor
    waitGroup sync.WaitGroup
}

func GetScheduler() Scheduler {
    return &RepeatScheduler{}
}

func (r *RepeatScheduler) singleRun() {
    defer r.waitGroup.Done()
    r.executor.Execute()
}

func (r *RepeatScheduler) AddExecutor(executor Executor) {
    r.executor = executor
}

func (r *RepeatScheduler) repeatRuns(parallelRuns uint64) {
    for count := 0; count < int(parallelRuns); count += 1 {
        r.waitGroup.Add(1)
        go r.singleRun()
    }

    r.waitGroup.Wait()
}

func (r *RepeatScheduler) Schedule(repeatRuns uint16, coolDown uint8, parallelRuns uint64) {

    for repeats := 0; repeats < int(repeatRuns); repeats += 1 {
        r.repeatRuns(parallelRuns)
        time.Sleep(time.Duration(coolDown))
    }

}
```

Could you point out to me what I could be doing wrong here? I'm using Go 1.16.3. When I debug my code, I can see the Execute() function being called but testify is not able to register the function call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call [`Called()`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/stretchr/testify/mock#Mock.Called) so that `mock.Mock` records the fact that `Execute()` has been called. As you are not worried about arguments or return values the following should resolve your issue:

```golang
func (m *MockExecutor) Execute() {
    defer m.wg.Done()
    m.Called()
}
```

However I note that the way your test is currently written this test may not accomplish what you want. This is because:

- you are calling `executor.wg.Wait()` (which will wait until the function has been called the expected number of times) before calling `executor.AssertNumberOfCalls` so your test will never complete if `Execute()` is not called at least the expected number of times (`wg.Wait()` will block forever).
- After `m.Called()` has been called the expected number of times there is a race condition (if `executor` is still be running there is a race between `executor.AssertNumberOfCalls` and the next `m.Called()`). If `wg.Done()` does get called an extra time you will get a panic (which I guess you could consider a fail!) but I'd probably simplify the test a bit:

```golang
scheduler.Schedule(2, 1, 4)
time.Sleep(time.Millisecond) // Wait long enough that all executions are guaranteed to have completed (should be quick as Schedule waits for go routines to end)
executor.AssertNumberOfCalls(t, "Execute", 8)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I see how ```m.Called()``` helps my use case. Also, ideally, it would have helped if I could have had a timeout for my Wait() but I'll take this one. Thanks.